# Why am I getting the Precognitive badge on random sites?

Tags: support, badges

It seems like an Area51 badge...

I've gotten it on MSO, SuperUser, ServerFault, Gaming, Web Apps... I think every SE site I'm registered to, except SO and Area51.

Is this intentional?

Comment: +1 - I just randomly got the new badge on all sorts of sites... except when I looked on my profile, I didn't have it :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<del>Yes, this is intentional.



I *believe* a more formal announcement of Precognitive/Talkative/Cross-site badges in general is planned for blog.SO.  Stay tuned.</del>

Apparently there was some miscommunication, and this was not intentional.  Precognitive badges are being rolled back*, and will be re-awarded in the near-ish future.

<sub>*Badge counts will be off for some users for a short period of time, not to exceed 24 hours.</sub>

Comment: I should've taken a screenshot while I had it. One day I will tell my children about the couple wonderful hours when I possessed the precognition badge

Comment: @Michael - if you got it, you'll get it again.  Just on a specific site instead of all sites.  Well... probably anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use my newly-bestowed powers of precognition and guess that, by awarding the badge to all of a persons accounts across multiple SOFU/SE sites, it is a way of advertising/promoting Area 51 (similar to how the Talkative badge advertises/promotes chat). In other words, these badges make such sites/features more visible as people stumble upon them while exploring SOFU/SE.

Comment: I knew you were going to say that.

Comment: Wouldn't a guy named gnostradamus always have it?

Comment: @Conrad: Yes, but now I have a shiny badge to prove it. I'm bona fide! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

My assumption is that because you saw a beta site through its public phase, its a badge for you. However since its a separate site and you deserve credit, its on all your sites