# Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S[OFU] badges?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

> Followed the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase

None of these sites had Area 51 proposals.

Comment: This is related to an apparent mistake in rolling out the badge, as discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71607/why-am-i-getting-the-precognitive-badge-on-random-sites).

Comment: Yes. They teach an important lesson to people who try to earn every last badge.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In addition to Popular Demand's "funny because it is true" comment ..

> [Precognitive badge] teaches an important lesson to people who try to earn every last badge.

The Precognitive badge appears in the badge list on every site to **announce the presence of [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), and its primary function.**

Since [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is itself about creating new sites *that don't exist yet*, the thought process is supposed to be:

> hmm, I can't get [the precognitive badge] on this site, but I could get it on some hypothetical future site I might be interested in.

Yes! Thus, based on seeing this badge and reading about it, a user is incentivized to:

1. [visit Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (and we provide a handy link in the badge description itself) -- win
2. look at upcoming site proposals -- win
3. follow likely proposals, which requires reading them and deciding if they have a chance -- win.

In conclusion: *win*.

The only minor downside is that Precognitive *could* incentivize following a lot of proposals you don't actually care about in hopes of getting the badge by chance. But this is really no different than the "fill out my profile with a bunch of garbage" approach to getting the Autobiographer badge. So the risk is very small, it's just a bronze badge, and the upside is IMO large.

Comment: So it's a variation of a Beta badge. You know what? This is actually really clever. +1

Comment: I think you should award it to Joel and yourself. At least you two followed and believed in the sites before they existed!

Comment: Oh no! I'm never gonna collect them all! My Pokemons....

Comment: What is Area 51?

Comment: @SilverHorn if you're seriously asking [this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: But this badge is not yet awarded to any user?? :-)[See this link Precognitive Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive)

Comment: @SJS: It's not awarded to anyone because Area 51 came about *after* S[OFU].  So none of the trilogy sites were in Area 51, and thus none ever really had a "commitment" phase or a concept of "following the proposal".  All sites effectively use the same engine, though, and there's not really a compelling reason to add code to except the main sites from showing the tag...it's just that no one has received it or ever will.