# Precognitive badge for stack overflow?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S[OFU] badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges)

I can get this badge for new upcoming sites on area51 but not sites that are already active e.g. Stackoverflow right?

Comment: How would a precognitive badge work for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Just one of those badges on  http://stackoverflow.com/badges that no one has gotten or can get I guess. http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive answered :)

Comment: Correct. Jeff has said this is by design, to make people more aware of A51. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges/71737#71737