# Why is there a Precognitive badge on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, badges

What's the point of having a Precognitive badge on Area 51 itself, since no one could have earned it?

It's on Stack Overflow to make people aware of Area 51, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72022/precognitive-badge-for-stack-overflow), but this reason wouldn't apply if you're already on Area 51.

Comment: SOFU/MSO also have it.

Comment: Jeff's *full* explanation linked to there is a complete answer to this question. Read it... not just someone's partial quote.

Comment: Convenience link to [Jeff's full answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71737/131713).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which reason? He gave three:

> - visit Area 51 (and we provide a handy link in the badge description itself) -- win **OK, not applicable**
> - look at upcoming site proposals -- **still applicable**
> - follow likely proposals, which requires reading them and deciding if they have a chance -- **still applicable**

The fact is, there is no real incentive for a user to use area51, even if they've seen it--till they see the precognitive badge somewhere. Agreed that a user will most probably have already started doing stuff in area51 before they check out the badges, but I see no pressing reason to remove it.

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Yeah it is. I was just thinking that it creates confusion about the badge, if someone sees it only there.