# Who has the most badges? Is there anyone who has them all?

Tags: discussion, badges

I was wondering who on Stack Overflow has the most number of **unique** badges, and if there is a person (or more) who has all of them.

EDIT: to be more clear, I mean the person with the most checkmarks on [the badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges). In other words having 1 "Good Answer" or 100 would make no difference.

Comment: They're not pokemon!

Comment: If they've got a lot of other badges it will be unlikely that they have the Tenacious or Unsung Hero badges.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check this out:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/971/distinct-badge-count-collected-by-users

There are badges that are now beyond reach - **Beta** is one

Also, `Jon Skeet` doesn't **need** to put any Bounty on any of his questions!
Nor will you likely see `Peer Pressure`: *Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower*

I should have added a RowNumber in there.. but the recurring theme you see with the top users is that - **none of them have `Unsung Hero`**.

---

This isn't **Pokémon** - you don't have to <s>Gotta</s> Catch 'Em All

Comment: You may not, but *I* do

Answer (score 6):

I wrote [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1354381/top100-users-having-the-most-non-tag-badges-badges-which-non-tag-badges-do-they) to answer this very interesting question.

1. There are as many tag badges as there are tags (with 100+ or 200+ questions). Thus, this query checks only for non-tag based badges.
2. Some tag-based badges can be earned multiple times (like Steward for all the review queues), so this query counts them only once. That is, we only ask "Does X have this badge at least once" and multiple badges count only once.
3. Badges which no one has earned on the site until now (like Constable on Stack Overflow), are unreachable on the SEDE without cross-DB queries. I was too lazy to implement it, so this query counts them as non-existent.

The results for Stack Overflow:

- There are 91 badges which can be earned.
- The top users now are [Ry-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry) (moderator) and [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848) (ex-mod) - both of them are missing 7 badges.

Some of them are:

- impossible to earn (Beta, Documentation*)
- some of them are very hard (Unsung hero)
- some of them would require some "talk" with the company ("Not a Robot" - requires personally meeting a Stack Exchange employee at an SE-sponsored event)
- some of them are possible ("Socratic", "Stellar question"), but it would require them to change their common usage pattern (like asking more questions)

The result:

| User Link | Badge count | Non-tag badges still not have |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Ry-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry) | 84 | Illuminator, Not a Robot, Documentation Beta, Stellar Question, Socratic, Unsung Hero, Beta |
| [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848) | 84 | Sheriff, Reversal, Not a Robot, Convention, Documentation Beta, Stellar Question, Beta |

Answer (score 5):

Nobody has every Stack Overflow badge. As ChrisF pointed out, it's unlikely that anyone with many badges would have Unsung Hero. Also, it's impossible to earn Precognitive on Stack Overflow. Jeff provided his reason for including it in the badge list [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges/71737#71737).

As for your other question... I could create a SEDE query to find out who has the most uniques, but since I barely ever touch SQL, I'm sure someone else will do it more quickly, accurately and efficiently than I would.

Comment: I was going to prove it by taking the intersection of [Publicist](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) and [Legendary](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary), but finding a badge that's *never* been awarded is much more direct.

Comment: @mmyers, not only has it never been awarded, it never will be.