# Should "triad" badges scale linearly?

Tags: discussion, badges, publicity-badges

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119247/150288) from [lockstep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159019/lockstep) to a [question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118484/booster-badge-should-be-golden-or-easier-to-achieve). Should "triad" badges such as [Announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer)/[Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/261/booster)/[Publicist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist) scale in such a way that the number of awarded `Bronze# / Silver#` is even with `Silver# / Golden#`?

As in his words:

> Right now, 4003 Announcer badges, 186 Booster badges and 93 Publicist badges have been awarded at SO. That is, the ratio of Announcer to Booster is about 1 to 21.5, while for Booster to Publicist it's only (exactly) 1 to 2.

What he says is true. Should a re-calculation of the badge's requirements be made to even it up?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. From the [badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=general&filter=gold):

> Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these.
>   They’re something of an accomplishment!

On the other end:

> Bronze badges are awarded for basic use of Meta Stack Overflow. They
>   are easy to earn.

The current ratios are consistent with these descriptions.

Comment: I think his point was that silver is just about as hard to earn as the gold badge...

Comment: My point is indeed as @yoda says: for example, a good ratio could be from 5:1 upward, so 500 bronze, 100 silver and 20 gold for 5:1; 1000 bronze, 100 silver and 10 gold for 10:1. Such examples look like they would reflect the descriptions better.