# Answer links counted for link-share badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, hyperlinks

This question is a **duplicate** of: [Do shared link to ANSWERS also count for Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114607/158428) but **specific in time**.

As of April, 2013 do links to answers count toward these badges?  I have reason to think not, though the most recent answer to that question suggests that they do.

If currently the do not count, I would like to make this a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/117903#117903):

> 2012-01-10: The Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges can now be [earned multiple times and they can also be earned for the same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118484/booster-badge-should-be-golden-or-easier-to-achieve/118509#118509). The time limit has also been removed. **Sharing direct links to answers now [also counts](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/816147#816147) towards these badges.**

Comment: Thanks.  I guess my estimate of views-per-Reddit-vote is inaccurate.