# Why it's made easier to get badges for asking questions vs answering them?

Tags: discussion, badges

As example getting 1000 views is just a matter of time. There are about 1.2m of awarded badges.

However, getting 10 upvotes for an answer is harder. Total is about 300k badges.

Also, questions has number of metrics - votes, views, favorites (total of all of related badges is about 2m) . However, answer just have one metric - votes (and total is about 400k badges).

**Update 1:** I believe badge is the reward (for something valuable for SO community). Granting more badges for questions implies that questions are more valuable than answers, which sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Because without questions, there wouldn't be answers.

Comment: 10 upvotes for an answer is also just a matter of time. I remember thinking the same thing several years ago (that it was hard to get +10 right away on an answer), and now not a week goes by that I don't earn a couple of Nice Answer and Enlightened badges for old answers.

Comment: There is only 1 metric for answers because you can't favour answers or view answers without viewing the question. There is just nothing else to measure besides votes.

Comment: @meta.michael with 3349 answers, that doesn't surprise me at all.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Point is - badges result from _continued participation_ far more than they result from one-time big events. I've probably earned < 10 Nice Answer badges (+10 votes) within 24 hours of answering a question, but I have earned 73 of them via the long tail.

Comment: Because solving a problem properly is harder than finding/asking it ?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: See my update

Comment: The reputation gain for upvote on a question is 5 and for an answer is 10. There where we show that good answers are more valuable than good questions. We still want to get questions, so skewing badges towards questions is a good balance.

Comment: @meta.michael: I think your case isn't applicable (being #123 in total rating). Most of the people (like me) who continue to participate time to time will have WAY-WAY more badges for questions than for answers. Actually, I can bet that huge amount of these 400k badges for answers will belong to top 500 on SO.

Comment: "Most of the people (like me) who continue to participate time to time will have WAY-WAY more badges for questions than for answers" I don't think that's necessarily true. You can be like me, someone who also doesn't participate as much as the big names, but almost only gives answers (in fact, Meta is the only site where I've asked a question, and 2 of the 4 were bugs)

Answer (score 6):

There are 15 question badges and 14 answer badges.

2 of the question badges are for offering/awarding bounties on other people's questions. You can earn these without asking a single question. So, we'll call the "real" number of question badges 13.

You can't count views to an answer, because all the answers are on one page. Unless you want to award *every* answer on that page, you can't do it.

You also can't favorite answers, so that's uncountable as well.

Additionally, tag-specific badges are *only* given out for answers

I simply don't see the issue. It actually feels easier for me to get badges from answers.

Comment: Hey.. You have just 4 question on SO. No wonder that it's easier for you to get badges from answers :) There is no issue per se. However, I believe current system tend to grand more badges for questions.

Comment: Yea, I hate asking questions. Call me stubborn, but I can usually puzzle things out after a while searching and pondering. FWIW, there's a good discussion on this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179552/question-related-badges-are-too-easy-to-get-can-we-change-the-popular-notable?rq=1).

Comment: Generally speaking, I don't like asking questions too. Usually I do that only when it will save me substantial amount of time.