# Why the users who ask more questions get more badges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, users

I am just surprised to see that the users who ask more questions on Stackoverflow sites get more badges than the users who give more answers.

Of course, the users who give more answers earn more reputation, but the badges get more easily for the users who ask more questions (worthy).

Is this the normal scenario of the site? (I verified many profiles before posting this question. Even my own stackoverflow profile says what i mean).

Comment: So, answerers gets more important reward, and askers gets more shiny one. Sounds good.

Comment: Related / possible dupe: [Why it's made easier to get badges for asking questions vs answering them?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203735)

Comment: Well, I think Stackoverflow is encouraging users to post more questions. Anyhow there are many good experts here to answer any critical question. Probably if one gets more badges for answers, there may be an unhealthy competition for posting answers, where a novice tends to answer a question of expert. That's not fair, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As badges are intended to reward good behavior, rewarding those who consistently ask good questions is both acceptable and intended behavior.

As such, badges are awarded when users ask good questions. While the quantity of such questions does tend to lead to a higher quantity of badges, this is only a side effect of the quality of the questions.

Additionally, as badges serve no other functional purpose besides display, it doesn't make too much of a difference if a few people accrue more badges over time, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

I disagree with your premise:

```
      Question  Answer  Ratio
Nice   152.3k   351.8k  1 : 2.3    
Good    38.1k    85.1k  1 : 2.2
Great    4.7k    10.4k  1 : 2.2
```

If you think ratio-wise, then here is the math:

```
Questions  6,621k
Answers   11,195k
Ratio      1 : 1.7
```

So you are more likely to get a badge on an answer than you are on a question.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is also talking about more *types* of badges for questions (the view and favorite count badges).

Comment: @jmac If you consider the profiles of new users, they ask more questions than they answer. Still, they earn more badges than a person who answered more than 100 questions. My point comes true in such cases.

Comment: @dskanth sure but it still depends on the quality of your answer because if your answer doesn't contain useful or new information you probably wont get a upvote ...

Comment: @Mart, 15-14 in the way of questions if you look at the badges page. You can total them up if you'd like.

Comment: @jmac: I didn't say the OP had a good argument. :-) I am just pointing out that he might be talking about a different metric.

Comment: @dskanth: Those badges would be deserved, having asked a good question. But you need to ask yourself: are you here to compete on badges and reputation, or are you here to provide great answers?

Comment: @Mart, pretty much any way you do the math, you've got a better shot when giving an answer than asking a question (all else being equal). While it's possible there is variation depending on the tag, time of day, or whatnot, I would wager that this is based more on the asker's perception rather than the actual data.