# Should the Booster threshold be reduced?

Tags: discussion, badges, publicity-badges

This has been asked in the past (e.g. [Booster badge should be golden or easier to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118484/booster-badge-should-be-golden-or-easier-to-achieve) ) but since that point a few patterns have developed which make the argument stronger.

The Nice/Good/Great questions and Popular/Notable/Famous questions and Nice/Good/Great answers   badges have been awarded such that the bronze badge awards is an order of magnitude higher than the silver badge awards, which is an order of magnitude higher than the gold badge:

On the other hand, the number of questions that earned the booster badge but not the publicist badge seems low relative to the number of publicist badges (323 publicist, 828 booster).

```
Type                 Bronze       Silver        Gold
Question Score       1.39  E5     3.42 E4       4.1  E3
Question Views       1.1   E6     4.61 E5       8.8  E4
Answer Score         3.237 E5     7.63 E4       9.2  E3
..
Shared Link Views    1.7   E4     8.28 E2       3.23 E2
```

Should the threshold for booster be reduced to something like 200?

Comment: I'm kinda confused. I thought you couldn't get the Booster badge without first getting the Announcer badge, sort of like how you can't get the Fanatic 100 day badge without first getting the Enthusiast 30 day badge...

Comment: @jmort253 announcer is the bronze badge.  The question is: given that there are few people who are getting the silver but not getting the gold, should the silver threshold be reduced or the gold threshold raised?  I suspect that reducing the silver threshold would make the awarded badges consistent with other bronze-silver-gold triples

Comment: Ok, I think I'm catching on now, I'm just really slow today. :D  The question score row is for the Nice/Good/Great question series of badges, the Questions views row is for the Nice/Good/Great answers series of badges, etc. And the numbers, in scientific notation, represent how many times that particular badge has been awarded in each category.