# How about removing the Beta badge from users that will never be able to earn it

Tags: feature-request, badges, beta-phase

Since this badge can't be earned by users joining after it was too late, I think it would be fair to remove it from their list. It's somewhat depressing to take a look at something you can't ever achieve.

Comment: FWIW, Jeff left entries for unattainable Precognitive badges on the badges page [intentionally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges/71737#71737).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be left - it's not like it massively increases the clutter of the badge page. What if I want to see a list of all the beta users? Also, how can it be depressing? Surely there are dozens of other unearned badges the non-Beta users can focus their interest on?

Comment: I understand your point, but it's that not ever being able to earn it somehow feels uneasy, at least to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is: Go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and find a proposal you're excited about. Now you can earn *that* Beta badge.