# Remove impossible badges from per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, badges, per-site-meta

Per-site metas lists some badges that are impossible to get. For example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges lists:

- [Altruist](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/48/altruist)
- [Benefactor](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/47/benefactor)
- [Beta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta)
- [Investor](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/45/investor)
- [Precognitive](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/65/precognitive)
- [Promoter](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/46/promoter)

But these are impossibly to get because per-site metas do not support bounties, were not in a beta stage or Area 51 proposals. I therefore suggest that these badges are removed from the per-site metas. They have no function and they are confusing.

There are already badges that are unavailable on per-site metas but available on the main sites:

- [Caucus](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/)
- [Constituent](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/election-participation-badges/)
- Convention
- Quorum

This seems to suggest that per-site metas should only contain badges that can be possibly awarded.

Comment: Your blank gravatar confused me! :(

Comment: Closely related: [Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of SOFU badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges/71737#71737)

Answer (score 17):

I'd think that removing them would be even *more* confusing.  Meta sites are where you go to learn about a Stack Exchange site.  As such, I think we want all the badges listed there.  The fact that some of the badges can't be awarded *on the Meta site* is irrelevant.  (There's one badge that can't be awarded on Stack Overflow, but it's still listed just for the sake of having a complete list.)

Maybe instead we could add an asterisk (linking to a note at the bottom of the page) to those badges that aren't awarded on a site or its Meta?

Comment: which badge is that?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The [Precognitive](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) badge can't be awarded on SO.

Comment: Why aren't there Quorum and Convention badges on per-site metas then?

Comment: @doncherry Good question!  That does seem to be inconsistent.

Comment: @doncherry Neither are the new election participation badges, Caucus and Constituent, on the per-site metas. I think the inconsistency should be fixed by *removing* all the impossible badges from per-site metas (rather than adding some impossible badges that are not there) and have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @N.N.: Or by **adding the missing badges**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Or adding a notice by the end of the list: **You are viewing the META.MySite badges. Didn't you intend to see the MySite badges [with link]** -- or something in that sense.

Answer (score 16):

We recently had a question over on User Experience which is related to what is asked here. The [accepted answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/60883/4679) to the question [Show not implemented functions to tease user](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60875/show-not-implemented-functionalities-to-tease-the-user) states:

> Quite simply don't do this. False expectations are the biggest source of a disappointing experience. It commits you to features that you may not be able/want to produce, users will assume very short timescales for this functionality to be in action, and it also highlights your apps weaknesses leading users to look for these elsewhere with your competitors.
>
> If you absolutely have to add teasers, make sure that it is clear at the beginning of the path that the feature is not implemented. There is nothing more annoying than putting in some effort to start a process only to have the rug pulled out from under you.

Don't have features that aren't implemented. It confuses users and creates false expectations. **Hide what isn't there**.

Comment: @VotetoClose Vote buttons could be better implemented, but the damage is less there, than on badges.

Comment: @BennySkogberg Moreover, the voting _is_ implemented, and by clicking on the vote button, the low-rep user learns how SE works (i.e., high-rep users can moderate the site), which is fine.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's terrible user-experience to show all those badges which are impossible to earn on the meta sites.

To see which badges you haven't got yet, you have to do extra work by going through ones which you can't even earn on the meta sites.

Please remove those completely from the badge pages on the metas.