# Let's get rid of the Precognitive badge on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S[OFU] badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges)

... because apparently, [only Jon Skeet has ever gotten it](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) and nobody else ever will. (Or is this a bug in the badge page?)

Comment: It's there to taunt us...

Comment: If this feature request were to be implemented, you would arguably deserve a "precognitive" badge for suggesting/predicting it. But you couldn't earn one, because it was removed as per your feature request.

Comment: Jon Skeet has it.. He just doesn't like to boast.

Comment: @JakeBadlands: It was a joke :/