# Why do I get to view the review link if I can't review anything?

Tags: discussion, review, privileges

At some point the [Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/) link at the top of the page became available to me. But why? I don't have enough rep on meta to do any reviews.

Is this something that happens automatically? If so, at what point? Or was it there all along and I just noticed it now?

[image: cant review]

Comment: May not be the answer in this specific case, but sometimes the team shows things you can't do/access just so you know they exist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71737/131713) for an example.

Comment: @PopularDemand I see, it's to motivate me to want to review, so when I get the privilege, I'll be right out of the gate! Gotcha! Now if there were only something to review.

Answer (score 4):

You're still allowed to use the old ones that haven't been converted yet (there's just normally not much to do there on Meta). The old ones run on different rules. Anyone can see them, but you can't officially "review" them unless you have the Strunk & White badge. The new ones just won't let you in without that amount of reputation.

It wouldn't be fair to hide the link for users who can still participate in the other tasks while they're being converted to the new system, and I'm not sure what kind of reputation requirement will even be placed on those. The reputation requirement on the current ones is to match the feature you're using in that task.

Comment: I hate the new system! I have been editing a few questions for grammer/spelling every time I log in for a long time! I always have to have my edits reviewed, but I try to do a good job. I look at this as community service. Now it is much more difficult for me to offer that service to the community. I am ~65% of the way to Strunk & White, and I had been looking forward to it. Now I guess the bar has been raised, but why? To discourage me?

Answer (score 3):

#### Actually...

... you CAN review the old stuff, just not the Review TASKS as they are in beta.

(not sure if you will still need 2k rep after beta is over)

[image]

**Edit:** Added freehand circle for clarification.

Comment: In other words, scroll down.

Comment: Now if only there were something to actually review so I could test out permissions.

Comment: @JimmyPena My screenshot is from SO, Meta review is empty for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's been there all the time.

You can review the lists of first questions, first answers and late answers from the old interface you can see at the bottom of the page.

[image]

(Admittedly not the most convenient or intuitive user interface ever made.)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately there's nothing to review right now so I can't test.