# Precognitive Badge

Tags: support, badges, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S[OFU] badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges)

In Stack Overflow, I saw [image: Precognitive] badge saying that its awarded to "Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase". What do this mean? No user is there having this badge.

Comment: You should post new feature request asking something like "Remove badges that can't be awarded from the list".

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard, can you edit my question please

Comment: No, it would render the answer useless plus make it whole different question. Nothing wrong in two separate questions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thank you. I will post a new question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nor will there ever be a user with this badge on Stack Overflow.

Stack Overflow (as well as Super User and Server Fault) predate Area 51.

Area 51 is a place for suggesting new Stack Exchange sites — if one follows a proposal for a new Stack Exchange site on Area 51 and the site goes out of beta, they get this badge on the new site.

The badge exists on all Stack Exchange sites, however, and on the trilogy sites it serves as a reminder that not all badges are achievable (or should be achievable!).

And the more important function - to announce and remind people of Area51!

Comment: More importantly it reminds people that Area 51 exists, I do believe that's (one of) the stated reasons

Comment: @BenBrocka - Thanks for that. Answer updated.