# A case for removing precognitive badge

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the Precognitive badge be listed in the list of S[OFU] badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges)

Since it's been said that [nobody will ever earn a badge for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146408/181100), why do we have it at all?

It seems like its asking to not be on the list of available/earnable badges.

Comment: It's not there so it can be awarded. It's there "to announce the presence of Area 51, and its primary function," [according to Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71737/131713).

Comment: This isn't a "case"; you don't have an argument for removing it.

Comment: on the badges page, the heading reads: "As you use Meta Stack Overflow to ask and answer questions, you’ll earn badges, which appear on your user page and in your user card."

Comment: Well, if you _really_ want to be nit-picky, that message never claims that the badges you can earn are the same as the ones listed below it.

Comment: @PopularDemand that's rich. :)

Comment: @Kristian It says all of the badges that can be earned show up there, not all of the badges listed there can be earned.

Comment: I *knew* you would open this question!

Answer (score 8):

Consistency with other sites is a good enough reason.

There is a handful of sites on the Stack Exchange network that the above statement is true for. For **most** of them, it is false.

It is also a good reminder that obsessing about obtaining all badges is not good for you...

In short - I disagree that it needs removing.

Comment: who is obsessing? in the context of SO, its an unachievable achievement. its weird.

Comment: @Kristian - I am sure some people do. Yes, it is unachievable, but that doesn't mean it should be removed.