# Is it possible to earn all the badges?

Tags: support, badges

What happens when you earn all the badges?
By any chance, is there some sort of 'hidden' badge for earning all the badges?

Comment: If there is a hidden badge (not saying there is) then telling you about it would kind of ruin the surprise - wouldn't it?

Comment: Closely related: [Should the "precognitive" badge be listed in the list of S\[OFU\] badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71712)

Comment: Your mom will be very proud. Seriously, though, this isn't even possible on Stack Overflow; some of the badges are retired (like Analytical) or were never available for SO (like Precognitive).

Comment: At that point your badge count will reset and a banner will drop down with the text "Level 2".

Comment: ...which is where all questions are displayed in ROT-13 and all [rate limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) are increased by 100%.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not possible. That's why I asked. :P  What if?

Comment: You get a signed picture of Jon Skeet giving you the thumbs up

Comment: I've heard level 3 is the even harder ROT-26 @JoshCaswell ... wait ...

Comment: It is ROT-26, @Bart, but it also uses the Unicode Dingbats table instead of the alphabet.

Comment: It would require every tag to have a minimum number of questions, therefore it's impossible because the goal posts keep moving. Were you to manage it you'd essentially be set for life on the kudos factor alone. But, never gonna happen.

Comment: "What will happen when you earn all the badges?" You'll banned for cheating, and then *all your badge are belong to me*...

Comment: I don't understand. Most of these comments are not useful and yet it's upvoted that apparently 'adds something useful to the post'. This is more like a 'like' button on Facebook where people for example compete who gets the most like for being the funniest...

Comment: You ask a question you apparently know has no satisfying serious answer to begin with, yet are surprised by comments of a similar nature?

Comment: This wasn't a joke or anything. I mean, why would I ask a question if I know an answer? And besides, these people including yourself know more about this website than I do. Not giving an excuse or anything but at least give me and other people (who are new to this website) a chance to get used to this website. Not all people can ask a question that will meet this website's standard all the time.

Comment: @user3315821 - no-one is stopping you from having a chance to get to know this website (or any of the other Stack sites). But part of "*getting to know*" means exploring and learning yourself. It's a little *early* in the day for you to want to be earning all badges - In fact you're a long way of earning *many* of them yet. Have a read through the help centre pages and search the site for previously asked questions. Then, if there's something on your mind of which there's no apparent info already present, ask away :)

Comment: I understand. But I've never said I want to earn them all. I was wondering whether it's possible to earn them all or not. And if it is possible, what will happen? But I know the answer now so thank you all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's going to be nearly impossible for *anyone*, save perhaps the founding members, to get *all* the badges, since you have to be a founding member to get a few. Also, you'd have to get all the tag badges, at which point you'd have millions or billions of rep..

Also, it's impossible to get a badge for having *all* the badges, since you don't have the badge that signifies that you have all the badges.

I sense a recursion joke in there somewhere.

Comment: I currently have a [Universal Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set) in my [Bag of Holding](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Bag_of_Holding).

Answer (score 5):

I have to double check this, but I *think* earning badges like Unsung Hero and Tenacious would be mutually exclusive to this, since they would indicate a lack of voting on a significant number of your posts (a requisite for quite a few of the other badges). I'm not certain it's impossible, but you'd need to do it in a very planned and calculated way. I'm not so sure earning all of them is possible.

No, there aren't any hidden badges (period). We've been discussing the idea of additional gold and silver badges that wouldn't be on the badge list, but discovered by earning them or happening upon someone that had. By design, these would be *extremely* difficult to get. It looks neat on paper, but some feel strongly against the idea, so it's still just an idea at this point.

I've also [got ideas for badges that sites *themselves*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222595/implement-badges-for-sites-themselves) could earn, like 'Happy Place' for great new user retention or 'Speedy Gonzales' for consistently low median times to the first up-voted answer to new questions. These would hang on a different wall showcased more as community than individual achievements, while those that participated heavily in earning them could possibly get individual gold / silver badges for doing so.

All still an idea.

Comment: Permanent secret hat will be so cool, you know. ;)

Comment: You don't lose Tenacious or Unsung Hero even if you later stop meeting the criteria, so that should be no problem. (I should know, I have them on SO.) Besides, there's no reason you couldn't have both a few really highly voted answers (to qualify you e.g. for Great Answer) and a large number of zero-score accepted ones at the same time. (The trick to getting those, should you want them for some reason, is to answer a lot of questions asked by low-rep users on unpopular topics.) On SO at least, though, Constable and Precognitive are the kicker.