# Are all stack exchange badges the same and if so why?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Can I introduce domain-specific badges to a stack exchange site, or rename them to domain-specific names? Also `Precognitive` makes no sense on SO.

Comment: *introduce* - Like with a meta post? A userscript? BTW this is really a dup of something something.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani  I don't understand any of that.

Comment: Do you have any examples in mind of potential domain specific badge names?

Answer (score 3):

The badge set is consistent across all Stack Exchange sites and it is for a reason... to avoid confusion and because the Stack Exchange network uses one structure on any stack, which allows you to achieve some results anywhere in the network. As an exception, Area 51 doesn't have a usual Stack Exchange structure, therefore the badges for it differ.

You can't request a badge to be made for a specific Stack Exchange site. If you post a badge request, it is considered to be related to any SE site, even if decide to do it  on a per-site meta.

(You can of course go and request a new badge for Area 51, but it doesn't *seem* to lack some badges; if you decide to do it, go to http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com, the meta for Area 51)

As for Precognitive badge on Stack Overflow: [it's left essentially to draw interest as a badge which is possible to earn somewhere else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges).