# Remove precognitive & beta badges on meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, area-51, per-site-meta

"Quorum" and "Convention" participation badges are listed on non-meta sites but not on the meta sites, sensibly (they are for participation on meta).  "Precognitive" and "beta" should also be not shown on the meta site badge lists, if they are not awarded.

I would also suggest hiding these badges on pre-Area 51 sites where they do not apply (e.g. Precognitive on StackOverflow).  Discussion on that proposal, however, can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges) (thanks, Oded).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges